# Pass Undefined Argument To Python Function [UX Driven]

Tags: python, function, interface, arguments, undefined

I would like to have a plotting interface (I do Allllooottt of plotting) where a user can put in an undefined variable.

***Desired Interface***

```
plot(ax,time,n1) # Returns Name Error
```

***Current Interface***

```
plot(ax,'time','n1')
```

I understand that this is likely a tall order, but I'm curious if the geniuses of Stack Overflow can find a way to do this. So far I've tried a decorator, but thats not working because the error isn't happening in the function, its happening in the calling of the function. Nevertheless I'm still interested in a solution... Even if its cumbersome.

**Current Code**

```
def handleUndefined(function):
    try:
        return function
    except NameError as ne:
        print ne
    except Exception as e:
        print e

@handleUndefined
def plot(self,**args):
    axesList = filter(lambda arg: isinstance(arg,p.Axes),args.keys())
    parmList = filter(lambda arg: arg in self.parms, args.keys())

    print axesList
    print parmList

fig,ax = p.subplots()
plot(ax,time,n1)
```

I'm designing a plotting interface, where people might make 20 plots / minute, so its important to give them less syntax here.

Comment: Why do you feel you need to handle undefined variable names? I really don't think this is solvable the way you've defined it.

Comment: I agree with you. I just wanted to show one solution I had been working on.

I think any solution will need to happen in the global namespace. Maybe i can make dummy parameters in the global namespace?

Comment: Are you just trying to save a couple of quote marks per call?

Comment: You are trying to use undefined variables, how do you expect to "work around" it ? what values should these undefined-variables hold ?

Comment: @MarkRansom Yes I am. I do similar commands to this ~ 20/minute when I'm working with this framework. It would be such a nice feature that I'm willing to work pretty hard for it.

Comment: @alfasin What I'm thinking is to create a singleton instance that maps all instances of the plotting container, and monitors in a separate thread what active parameters exist in the dataset. It would assign for instance globally time = 'time'. For my use case that might be beneficial. I could also use that to help with a memory leak I have.

Comment: You type `plot(ax,'time','n1')` 20 times per minute? That's impressive.

Comment: Its not just a question of an undefined variable - where is the data that you want to plot? You say you currently do `plot(ax,'time','n1')` - but there is no plotable data there.

Comment: @tdelaney I work for a jet engine company, and we're always doing investigative type analysis...plot one thing. then another. then another. I know this is kind of a laughable problem but its really annoying to have to close quotes all the time when you're changing things.

The data we have is within self. so i have a get attribute look up self.time -> self.__call__('time') -> self.data[:,self.parms['time']]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I had given up on finding the solution to this but low and behold I found a solution. It wasn't obvious but we can rely on pythons magic methods to actually link these variables into a global list **all** which is python's first stop in finding a variable.

I found a solution in which you can append something to all by using an @public decorator:
[http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576993-public-decorator-adds-an-item-to-**all**/](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576993-public-decorator-adds-an-item-to-__all__/)

From there the solution was something like this

```
    @public
    class globalVariable(str):
        _name = None      
        def __init__(self,stringInput):
            self._name = stringInput
            self.__name__ = self._name

        def repr(self):
            return self._name

# Hopefully There's a strong correlation
xaxis = globalVariable('trees')
yaxis = globalVariable('forest')

#Booya lunchtime
plot(trees,forest)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's considered evil (or at least a bad practice) to use `exec` but that's the only way I could come up with setting up a variable dynamically from the value of a string which is unknown before runtime:

```
strg = 'time' # suppose this value is received from the user via standard input 
exec(strg + " = '" + strg + "'")
print time # now we have a variable called 'time' that holds the value of the string "time"
```

Using this technique, you can define variables that will hold "their own name" dynamically.

Comment: This is a good solution. What I haven't answered yet is how to do this dynamically.

Thanks for your response :)